# Google maps. Blank Image

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I tried everything I could think of, but the first time the page loads I have a blank google gray image, after refresh is working.

```
<script>
var latitude,longitude;
function GetLocationInstant() {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': '7521 Reindeer Ct, Las Vegas, NV 89147' /* This address will come from a post variable*/ }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
            // console.log("Latitude: " + latitude + "\nLongitude: " + longitude);
        } else {
            console.log("geocoder.geocode() failed.<?php echo $address; ?>");
        }
    });
};


var map;
function initializeInstant() {
    var image = "http://example.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/icon.gif";
    // console.log(latitude,longitude);
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 20,
        center: myLatlng,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),mapOptions);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        icon: image
    });
}
GetLocationInstant();
if ('undefined'!==latitude&&'undefined'!==longitude)
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initializeInstant);
</script>
<div style="height: 200px;margin-bottom: 20px;padding: 0px" id="map-canvas"></div>
```

**How can I get the a google map Image searching by address?**

EDIT: http://jsfiddle.net/qzygw4jL/4/

Comment: have you checked your browser's console for any errors?

Comment: there are no errors.

Comment: Your code is not complete.  Copied and pasted your code onto a [JsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/qzygw4jL/) and it appears to be missing the google apis.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question, including any HTML/CSS/external javascript required to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Added fiddle. Is exactly how is in my page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Geocoding is an asynchronous operation and you're not waiting for the result before initializing the map. You should call `initializeInstant()` inside the geocoder callback like this:

```
var latitude,longitude, map;
function GetLocationInstant() {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({ 
        'address' : '7521 Reindeer Ct, Las Vegas, NV 89147 '
        }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
            // Initialize map after address is found
            initializeInstant();
        } else {
            console.log("geocoder.geocode() failed.<?php echo $address; ?>");
        }
    });
};

function initializeInstant() {
    var image = "http://example.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/icon.gif";
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 20,
        center: myLatlng,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),mapOptions);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        icon: image
    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", GetLocationInstant);
```

**[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/qzygw4jL/6/)**